# Estimating the slope of tangent line in $\frac{ A(2.1)-A(2) }{0.1}$

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, slope

---

I am trying to understand or find a proof for the following statement:

$$ \frac{ A(2.1)-A(2) }{0.1} \approx f(2) \approx1 $$

f is defined in this graph:
[image]

And A is the full rectangular area bounded by x axis on the lower part and by y= f(t) in the upper part like the entire pink-shaded region.

I believe $$\frac{ A(2.1)-A(2) }{0.1}$$ is the slope of the line tangent to the graph of A at the given interval.

But I do not understand why this is approximately f(2).

Comment: You're working with the Average Value Theorem - a variant of the Mean Value Theorem but with integrals. I'll see if I can drum up an answer.

Comment: $A(2.1)$ is the rectangle $A(2)$ plus another rectangle of base $0.1$ and height $f(2.1).$  If $f$ is continuous, then $f(2)$ is a reasonable first approximation to $f(2.1)$

Comment: @saulspatz that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that A(x) represent the area under f(x) from 0 to x, thus for the FTC

$$A(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt  \implies A’(x)=f(x)$$

then

$$ A’(2)\approx \frac{ A(2.1)-A(2) }{0.1} \approx f(2) \approx1 $$